# Can someone please show me how to call my method in the main class

Tags: java

I am very new to Java please go easy on me.
I have tried many different ways to call

```
public static double lbs2kg(double w)
{
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter weight");
    w = s.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The weight is");
    System.out.println(w*0.453592);
    return w;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // I assume its some variation of this!!!
    HelloWorld().lbs2kg(double w);
}
```

I have tried a few different ways

Comment: Your teacher (its obvious) probably wants you to do only the conversion in the method. The method returns the double, which you can then use to print the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it a `double` value

```
lbs2kg(5); // like 5 or 5.0 either works
```

Better picture

```
public static void main(String[] arg){

    double number = 5;
    lbs2kg(number);

}
```

Really, your method should return void unless you really want to return the value. But with all the printing going on in the method, maybe a `void` return is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the static method in a static way, such as...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double w = 2.0;
    HelloWorld.lbs2kg(w); 
}
```

FYI - you are passing in a double, but then reading a new value from System.in, so one of those is not needed...